# jQuery - Add click to front of queue

Tags: javascript, jquery

Upon load I have some animation running, with action buttons on the screen as the page is still set to animate. At present, when a user clicks on a new jQuery action (click(); event) then that is added to the back of the queue - and it doesn't complete until the Document Ready completes. How can you prioritise new events over existing jQuery items in the queue? I want the click to run instantly, and the queued items to continue running after this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `stop()` to clear the active item on the queue of an element.

[Stop() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/stop)

Comment: Thanks, wouldn't this then stop the whole queue and I wouldn't be able to resume from where it stopped? Thanks

Comment: No, if you read the docs it states that it only stops the animation that is currently running. If you want to clear the entire queue use `.stop(true)`

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying! I've got a foreach () which loads seperate ajax requests and animations, how can I intercept to run a new ajax request when a button is pressed and resume back to the foreach? Thanks again

Comment: That depends entirely on your HTML structure. It would best to start a new question for that, including all the relevant HTML and JS code.

Comment: Hi, thank you. I have already put on another question, but didn't get the desired response (I may have been over exaggerating the times a bit, but my point was still there). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28596188/jquery-add-click-event-to-front-of-queue

Answer (score 0):

If I was you I would look into Stop(), It should be what you want to achive the solution for your problem.

Link for the [documentation](http://api/jquery.com/stop)

Comment: Thanks, wouldn't this then stop the whole queue and I wouldn't be able to resume from where it stopped? Thanks